# Cron syntax with Java EE 5?

Tags: cron, timer, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, java-ee-5

Timer Tasks in Java EE are not very comfortable. Is there any util, to configure timer with cron syntax like "0 20 20 * * "?

I wonder, if it would be a good way to use Quartzinside (clustered) Java EE application. According to http://www.prozesse-und-systeme.de/serverClustering.html (german page) there limits with Quartz and Java EE clustering:

- JDBC must be used as job store for Quartz
- Only cluster associated Quartz instances are allowed to use this JDBC job store
- All cluster nodes must be synchronized to the split second
- All cluster nodes must use the same quartz.properties file

I would prefer an easier way for configuration of timer service, instead an not Java EE managed scheduler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quartz definitely support cron-like syntax (with the [`CronTrigger`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html)) but your requirements are not clear. Also maybe have a look at [Jcrontab](http://jcrontab.sourceforge.net/) or [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/).

---

As a side note, the ability to declaratively create cron-like schedules to trigger EJB methods is one of the most important enhancement of the Timer Service in EJB 3.1 (using  the [`@Schedule`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) annotation). Below, an example taken from [New Features in EJB 3.1](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=NewFeaturesEJB31):

```
@Stateless
public class NewsLetterGeneratorBean implements NewsLetterGenerator {

    @Schedule(second="0", minute="0", hour="0",
                  dayOfMonth="1", month="*", year="*")
    public void generateMonthlyNewsLetter() {
        ... Code to generate the monthly news letter goes here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to use JEE only stuff. TimerService.createCalendarTimer(ScheduleExpression) is my favorite. Details are available at http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318

Comment: @marabol If JEE6 is an option, it's a wise choice indeed.